# Get database data with LIKE and order by

Tags: php, mysql, database

I use this code but not work:

```
$sql =  mysql_query('SELECT etchat_user_id, etchat_username, etchat_userprivilegien , emtiyaz FROM db1_etchat_user WHERE etchat_userprivilegien LIKE "%hhh%" ORDER BY emtiyaz DESC');
```

Nothing to show.
I have very words like hhh in my database but this code don't show anything.

Comment: what happens when you run that query in phpmyadmin

Comment: did you try using single quotes? as '%hhh%' ?

Comment: nothing.I think this code is correct but coulden't get similiar data from database.

Comment: So is your query not 'working' or does it just return an empty result where you expect something to be returned?

Comment: Yes , I use single quotes but not work.

Comment: It just empty result.

Comment: When you say the result is empty, do you mean it just doesn't output anything to the screen? What happens if you do `var_dump($sql);` after the command in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing your quote usage.

```
mysql_query
     ("SELECT etchat_user_id, etchat_username, 
      etchat_userprivilegien , 
      emtiyaz FROM db1_etchat_user WHERE 
      etchat_userprivilegien LIKE ('%hhh%') 
      ORDER BY emtiyaz DESC");
```